# web scraping - No records found

Tags: html, r, xml, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to rbind series of HTML Tables (from different pages with same col names) but some pages have "no records" , I want to skip such pages or assign NULL to the dataframe.

Example Dataframe 1

```
url="http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/28081.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=1;innings_number=1;orderby=start;result=1;template=results;type=batting;view=match"

Batting=readHTMLTable(url)

Batting$"Match by match list"

Batting<-Batting$"Match by match list"
```

Dataframe 2

```
    url="http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/625383.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=1;innings_number=1;orderby=start;result=2;template=results;type=batting;view=match"



Batting=readHTMLTable(url)

Batting$"Match by match list"

Batting<-Batting$"Match by match list"
```

There are several such Dataframes which have records in tabular form and some that don't have records

When I rbind the one with no records is causing error for final dataframe

```
final_DF<-rbind(Dataframe1,Dataframe2)
```

How do I resolve this!?

PS: And for each url query I'm adding certain set of columns(say 5 additional columns using cbind) based on my requirement to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
require(rvest)
require(tidyverse)

urls <- c(
  "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/28081.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=1;innings_number=1;orderby=start;result=1;template=results;type=batting;view=match",
  "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/625383.html?class=2;filter=advanced;floodlit=1;innings_number=1;orderby=start;result=2;template=results;type=batting;view=match"
)

extra_cols <- list(
  tibble("Team"="IND","Player"="MS.Dhoni","won"=1,"lost"=0,"D"=1,"D/N"=0,"innings"=1,"Format"="ODI"),
  tibble("Team"="IND","Player"="MS.Dhoni","won"=1,"lost"=0,"D"=1,"D/N"=0,"innings"=1,"Format"="ODI")
)

doc <- map(urls, read_html) %>% 
  map(html_node, ".engineTable:nth-child(5)")

keep <- map_lgl(doc, ~class(.) != "xml_missing")

map(doc[keep], html_table, fill = TRUE) %>% 
  map2_df(extra_cols[keep], cbind)
```

The critical part is the `discard` which removes all list-elements of class *"xml_missing"* e.g. the empty ones.

I comparison to your code i use CSS selector to specify the `html_node` that should inherit the table. See http://selectorgadget.com/

Also your `rbind` is done internally by `map2_df` (the last row)

This results in: (using `%>% {head(.[,c("Bat1", "Runs", "Team")])}`)

```
  Bat1 Runs Team
1    0    0  IND
2    3    3  IND
3  148  148  IND
4   56   56  IND
5   38   38  IND
6   20   20  IND
```

Comment: Actually I got additional columns to add for each url ,(Example:  cbind("Team"="IND","Player"="MS.Dhoni","won"=1,"lost"=0,"D"=1,"D/N"=0,"innings"=1,"Format"="ODI") .

Comment: @chdeepak see my update. This way you can cbind additional information to the scraped data.

Comment: thanx for responding, I've tried with the updated code. I have added additional urls. it's throwing an error#### Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Can not automatically convert from character to integer in column "Runs".

Comment: Then please get your column types right. I think this question is answered. Identify/isolate the error and open a new question with it.

Comment: Yea....I'm on that. well thanx for your time. and sorry my previous edit accidentally happened in answer.